# Geolocation API not working, nor is Google Maps "My Location"

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-geolocation

I must be doing something wrong here, but I can't find what...  I'm making a page for my company website that, among other things, provides directions to job sites based on the user's current location.  To get their location, I'm using the [Geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/) as implemented in Firefox (I was testing with FF9 and now FF10).  For the moment I'm testing with the sample code that is in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_API):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Geolocation Test</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var gl;

function displayPosition(position) {
  var p = document.getElementById("p");
  p.innerHTML = "<table border='1'><tr><th>Timestamp</th><td>" + position.timestamp +
    "<tr><th>Latitude (WGS84)</th><td>" + position.coords.latitude + " deg</td></tr>" +
    "<tr><th>Longitude (WGS84)</th><td>" + position.coords.longitude + " deg</td></tr></table>";
}

function displayError(positionError) {
  alert("error " + positionError.code);
}

try {
  if (typeof navigator.geolocation === 'undefined'){
    gl = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
  } else {
    gl = navigator.geolocation;
  }
} catch(e) {}

if (gl) {
  gl.getCurrentPosition(displayPosition, displayError);
} else {
  alert("Geolocation services are not supported by your web browser.");
}
</script>

<body>
<p id='p'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

(copy/paste this into a text editor, save as "whatever.html", and drag the file to the browser to open it)

Very simple code, and it actually worked fine last Thursday, 01/26/12.  (I know, I know, people say "It worked yesterday!" when they actually goofed something up, but I swear it really did.)  Since then, however, it's been giving me error code 2, "POSITION_UNAVAILABLE".  I have tried it with my work computer on my work network, my work and home computers on my home internet connection, and my work computer on a wifi hotspot from my phone, and it gives error code 2 every time.

I thought maybe I'd somehow goofed something up in my browser or my network settings or something (though I couldn't imagine what), so I tried the next test, which everyone should be able to do:

1. Go to maps.google.com.
2. Search for "seattle" (or some other location, whatever).
3. Click the "Get Directions" button.
4. In the directions boxes on the left, "A" should say "My location" and "B" should say "seattle".  (If it doesn't say "My Location" in A, type "m" into the box, and the auto-populating dropdown will usually have "My Location" as the first option.)
5. Click the "GET DIRECTIONS" button.
6. Firefox should pop up a message saying maps.google.com wants to know your location.  Click "Share Location".
7. After a couple seconds, it should either show you directions from somewhere (wherever it thinks your server is) to Seattle, or the "A" box should go blank and it'll say "Could not find your location" or similar toward the top of the map.

And here's the weird thing: I have never yet gotten this to work on any computer.  My work computer (on both FF10 and Chrome), my coworkers' computers, my home computer, and my GF's work computer all do the same thing; none can find the location.

So my question is: Is the location API down or something, or am I screwing something up?  I haven't been able to find any indications online of an API outage, and it seems like an outage is very unlikely, but if so, why does it not work on any computer I've tried it on?  Can anyone else duplicate these findings or know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your script works fine, and the location feature in Google Maps as well (FF9.0.1)

Where are you? (I mean physically) It is possible that if you are in some remote place, Google cannot compute your location yet! Try it out in some large city maybe...

The other possibility would be that you do not have access to Google's location servers, as if your ISP blocked it...

Comment: Yep, the API is up and running. Since you've tried computers belong to multiple people, I'd also rule out that you set your browser to never share your location. It sounds more plausible that your browsing is trying but failing because something is tanding on its way.

Comment: I'm in Portland, Oregon.  I hope Google knows where that is. :)  And I could see one ISP blocking it, but I've tried from what should be at least four separate providers: my work internet access which is actually through an intranet that connects to the outside world somewhere on the east coast, and then my home internet ISP, my Android phone's wifi hotspot, and my GF's work connection.  It pops up the box asking if I want to share the location each time, so that part is working fine, but then it gives back error code 2 with my test code, and can't find "My Location" on Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to be working in Chrome, but not in FF. The error I am getting in FF is position unavailable, meaning probably that FF's location service doesn't have access to my wifi network. I assume the error you're getting is error 2 in your alert?

If you use Firebug, you can set a stop point on line 15. When it stops, click on positionError in the Watch panel to the right and check out what the code is. Mine reads: code 2 which translates to Unavailable.

I suggest you have some other code to handle this instance.

Comment: The positionError.code is dumped out in the JS alert box; it is code 2 every time.  As far as I can tell, the Geolocation API should work as long as you have any kind of internet access, and should actually be more accurate on wifi in many cases since Google has mapped the location of a bunch of wifi hotspots.  But that's why I've tried multiple computers and connection types.  In my production code on the company intranet I do have code to handle not being able to find the location (it picks a default), but not finding the location makes it much less useful.

Comment: Well, 3 points: 1) Google may not have mapped all your internal wifi networks, may not actually know where those are. 2) Not sure why FF is not getting the location when Chrome does, they should use the same location provider. Are you getting the same results regardless of browser? 3) Is this an internal only site? If so, you may need to upgrade to Maps API for Business, Google's Enterprise version.

Comment: I thought the Geolocation API should at least get the location of your ISP by your IP address if it does not know where the wifi point is.  Anyway, as noted in my post, Chrome does not get the location either in Google Maps.  And with the simple HTML test code, it does not even pop up a message to ask if I want to share the location, even after setting the option to "Allow all sites to track my physical location".  The test code gives error code 1, "PERMISSION_DENIED".